# 'dict' object has no attribute friend

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I receive this error: Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'dict' object has no attribute 'friendship'. The problem is when i try to get the value of friend.friend in the custom template tag. The module 'friends_for_user' is right. I have:

models

```
class FriendshipManager(models.Manager):

  def friends_for_user(self, user):
     friends = []
     for friendship in self.filter(from_user=user).select_related(depth=1):
        friends.append({"friend": friendship.to_user, "friendship": friendship})
     for friendship in self.filter(to_user=user).select_related(depth=1):
        friends.append({"friend": friendship.from_user, "friendship": friendship})
     return friends
```

template tags

```
 def render(self, context):
    user = self.user.resolve(context)
    num = self.num.resolve(context)

    my_friends = Friendship.objects.friends_for_user(user)

    potential_friends = []
    for friend in my_friends:
        potential_friends.append(Friendship.objects.friends_for_user(friend.friend))  //This line is the error.

    context[self.context_name] = potential_friends
    return ''
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're using a dictionary not an object.
Try 
 potential_friends.append(Friendship.objects.friends_for_user(friend['friend']))